# Display users as HTML table

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display users of wordpress as a table just like
https://stackoverflow.com/users

The recommended function is wp_list_authors, but it is not clear how can customise
the layout.

Say I want to display users in cells of table 5 x 5 with get next page link.

Please advice.

Let me explain a bit.

Unlike **get_users_of_blog**  **wp_list_authors** does not return an array. If it would - then
having an array I can build any table using `foreach`. But **wp_list_authors** builds anchor tags on its own and returns monolith html block. The only option to control layout would be passing some sort before and after tags. But this function does not provide this sort of functionality.

Comment: Eugh. Layout tables. Isn't this 2011?

Comment: He doesnt say layout tables, he just wants them in a nice tabular view, for which tables are perfectly fine. Actually, that SO page uses tables too!

Comment: Tables are still a valid way of presenting DATA.

Comment: Tables are a perfectly fine way of presenting **tabular**  data. The litmus test for tabular data is "Does every item in a column have something in common? Does every item in a row have something in common? Is the 'something' different for each column / row?". In this case, it is just a 5x5 grid of data, not a table. It should be a wrapped list. Stack Overflow is not a bastion of quality HTML.

Comment: David, can you provide link or example

Comment: @DavidDorward: 2011 is not about avoiding `<table>`s always, ever. It's about using them only where appropriate, i.e. for displaying data, like this question is about. It has nothing to do with layout.

Comment: @Tomalak — As mentioned. Tables are fine for tabular data. This is not tabular data. This is a list of data expressed in the form of a grid. The list is the structure of the data, the grid is the layout. The grid should not be achieved using tables (which is what the example given in the question uses)

Comment: @Captain Comic — At the most basic `li { float: left }` but you'd probably want explicit widths, `clear` set on every one where `(n%5) == 0`, and so on.

Comment: @David: What on earth do you think tabular data is, then?

Comment: @David: Oh, I re-read the question and you're right. Sozzles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, there's no function like `get_authors()`, but you can do it by a raw SQL query in a custom template:

Update: For pagination

I'm not sure if you can use the built-in WordPress pagination to do that, as the `paged` param only appear to posts. You could fill a global $post var in a loop or something... There's a lot of approaches, but let's go for the "PHP" one. =D

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $limit = 25;
    $offset = ($o = trim($_GET['offset'])) ? $o : 0;
    $users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_nicename ... FROM {$wpdb->users} LIMIT $offset,$limit");
?>
<?php foreach ($users as $user) : ?>
    <div class="someclass">
        <?php echo $user->user_nicename; ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ($i++ % $number_of_columns == 0) : ?>
        <div class="padder"></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

To simulate the table appearance, just float "someclass" left and put a fixed width on it. The "padder" div (float left and width 100%) will ensure that the cells will be aligned by the highest one in that row.

And for the pagination links:

```
<?php $n = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(ID) FROM {$wpdb->users}"); ?>
<?php $o = $offset - $limit; ?>
<?php if ($offset > 0) : ?>
    <a class="prev" href="?offset=<?php echo $offset - $limit; ?>">Previous</a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $o = $offset + $limit; ?>
<?php if ($o < $n) : ?>
    <a class="next" href="?offset=<?php echo $o; ?>">Next</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Code from brain to keyboard. Not tested, again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but then I can use get_users_of_blog. Doc says it is deprecated but it is used by wp_list_authors that is not deprecated. So a non-deprecated function uses deprecated?

Comment: @CaptainComic: Deprecation isn't inherited. The authors should update the implementation of `wp_list_authors`, but that they haven't doesn't make it deprecated itself.

Comment: The SQL table structure for wp_users won't change in some years, so you don't have to worry if this code will crash in the future. Deprecation is not a problem. =D

Comment: Vinicius, can you update your code. The query returns 200 records I need to display first 25 and diplay next page button.

Comment: Updated. It's better to test all vars, $_GET values and other values for them to match integers. But I think that's what you need.